# The hover action for a browser action popup for a webextensions add-on stays partially highlighted after hover release

Tags: html, css, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions, firefox-quantum

I'm working on a webextension and I have a new problem ever since I upgraded to firefox quantum: The popup menu for my extension messes up the hover by staying partially highlighted. [image: gif].

As you can see in the gif, the first element remains partially highlighted even when I am hovering over the bottom and the bottom remains partially highlighted even when I am hovering over the top.

This only happens in firefox and works just fine in google chrome.

What do I need to do to fix this issue? Is there anything in specific I am missing or is this an issue with the new firefox update?

I've created a minimal extension to reproduce the issue:

Create a manifest.json with the following contents:

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "browser_style": true,
    "default_popup": "choose_page.html"
  }

}
```

Create a document called choose_page.css with the following contents:

```
html, body {
  width: 250px;
}

.common {
}

.common:hover {
  background-color: #CFF2F2;
}
```

and an html page called choose_page.html with the following contents:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="choose_page.css"/>
  </head>

<body>
  <div class="common">Enable/Disable</div>
  <div class="common" id="sidebar">Show/Hide</div>
</body>

</html>
```

I believe this is a bug on firefox's part, so I've submitted a bug here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1422187